# Angular Routing: Define Multiple Paths for Single Route

Tags: javascript, angular, routes

I've seen several answers to this, but I'm not sure if they necessarily "fit" my scenario (I'm not trying to create parent/child routing relationships or anything like that). In my case I have a component that's responsible for adding new widgets, or editing existing widgets. My routes are defined like so:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'widget/add',
    component: ManageWidgetComponent,
    canActivate: [CanActivateViaRoleGuard],
    data: { roles: ['Admin', 'User'] }
  },
  {
    path: 'widget/:id/edit',
    component: ManageWidgetComponent,
    canActivate: [CanActivateViaRoleGuard],
    data: { roles: ['Admin', 'User'] }
  },
];
```

`path` is a `string` so it can't accept an array of values or anything like that. Is there a way to specify multiple paths for a single route so I don't have to duplicate the other parts of the route (the component, canActivate, and data parts)?

**Note**: The paths cannot be changed due to application requirements (i.e. I can't just make a single `manage` path).

**Edit**: My `ManageWidgetComponent` already has the correct logic for handling Create vs. Edit. That part's fine.

Answer (score 2):

I think you could do something like this :

```
const routes: Routes = ['widget/add', 'widget/:id/edit'].map(path => {
 return {
    path: path,
    component: ManageWidgetComponent,
    canActivate: [CanActivateViaRoleGuard],
    data: { roles: ['Admin', 'User'] }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this format :

```
  {
     path: 'widget/:id/add-edit',
     component: ManageWidgetComponent,
     canActivate: [CanActivateViaRoleGuard],
     data: { roles: ['Admin', 'User'] }
  },
```

and in ManageWidgetComponent use fallowing code to check if there is a value for "id"? if there is no value for id so you are adding a new user and if there is a value for "id" so you are editing a user.

```
this.route.params.subscribe((params: any) => {
        if (params.id) {
            //////you are editing a user
        }else{
            ///// you are adding a new user
        }
     }
);
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. You can't navigate to `widget/add-edit` (the route isn't found). And I can't change the paths as they are anyway (application requirement).

Comment: try this one   path:[ 'widget/add',' 'widget/:id/edit','],

Answer (score 0):

By convention, there is a one to one relationship between a route and a path (they are basically the same thing), So you can't have different paths for a single routes.
But you can have different paths that loads the same component (and that's what you're doing in the example above)

A way to solve this problem would be :

```
{
   path: 'widget/:id',
   component: ManageWidgetComponent,
   canActivate: [CanActivateViaRoleGuard],
   data: { roles: ['Admin', 'User'] }
},
```

Then you can navigate to `widget/add` or `widget/123`

And in `ManageWidgetComponent`:

```
this.route.params.subscribe((params) => {
    if (params.id === 'add') {
        // Add new user
    } else {
        // Edit user with id = +params.id
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the info! Sadly I cannot change the paths themselves (they have to be `/widget/add` and `widget/:id/edit`), due to application requirements.